# Copy rows from access table to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have the following code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\ActionList.accdb"
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM Actionlist;"
    cn.Open strConnection
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

My purpose is to get all rows from a certain table to copy in my Excel sheet. I though something this easy would be all over the internet, but I cannot seem to find it. I would like the rows to start from A2, since I've already added the access table to my worksheet by using the built-in function of Excel. I want to do this manually however, to add certain filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need, what you have, but also

```
for f= 0 to rs.fields.count-1
    range("a1").offset(0,f).value=rs.fields(f).name
next f

range("a2").copyfromrecordset rs
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch do `DAO`, so that `CopyFromRecordset()` will work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String
    Set Dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\ActionList.accdb")
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM Actionlist;"
    Set rs = Dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    'Add Head lines:
    for i= 0 to rs.fields.count-1
        range("a1").offset(0,i).value=rs.fields(i).name
    next f
    'Add Data:
    range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    'Colse resources:
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Dbs.Close
    Set Dbs= Nothing
End Sub
```